# Is there an debug equivalent in C# to javascript's console.dir()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio community 2015. Now when I need some debug info I am using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. I would like to know if there is a way to do the same with objects/classes like in javascript's `console.dir()`

For example

```
someObject = { x: 1, y: true, z: "some text"}
console.dir(someObject);
```

give me

[image: console.dir()]

I like to get this info to check (for example) parameters that I send to event handlers functions.

Thanks

Comment: VS has a good debugger.. Learn how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community edition has immediate pane and code insight. So you can do this:

[image: Screenshot of VS debugging session, red circles included]

1. Open the immediate pane (Debug > Windows > Immediate) and type the name of the object to dump.
2. Step past the first assignment, then hover the mouse pointer over the identfier. A popup (that can be pinned) opens. You can drill down if the object has multiple "levels", just like in `console.dir`.

Comment: Ah!! I have to always use a break point for be able to look it don't I ? In run mode (I think that is the name) it will not work?

Comment: If you need a non-interactive version, [consider this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4504249/1132334) or this, as previously suggested in a comment on the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/360309/1132334

Comment: Yes, I was looking to that post too, thank you for your help. I get in almost my c# question down votes :/